# Installing Python 3.8 on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install Python 3.8 on my Windows 10 system (64 bit). After downloading python 3.8 (32 bit) I tried to install it to C:\Python38. But after choosing the folder it is showing error message that "You don't have enough permission". By default it is choosing the folder c:\Users\INDIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32. The problem is when I am using Powershell and writing this code:

```
import openpyxl 
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
wb.get_sheet_names()
```

it is showing error "<'stdin'>:1: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_names (Use wb.sheetnames)

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're asking two different questions: 1) why you do not have enough permissions and 2) why you're getting the warning. Answers: 1) ask your system admin; 2) this is not an error, it's just a deprecation warning, which means that you shouldn't be using this function since it'll soon be removed because the library already provides another/better API for this

Comment: For second what should I do? will the program still work?

Comment: It will continue to work for some time, until the devs completely remove this API. Why don't you "use `wb.sheetnames`", as the error message suggests?

Comment: You should focus on a single question, rather than both Python 3.8 install issues and openpyxl usage issues.